# Getting logged out immediately after logging into an Apache webapp (OpenClinica)

Tags: apache, http, redirect

I am running an OpenClinica install on my webserver and experience the following problem on Google Chrome only:

- I access the landing page
- I log into the root (or any other) account
- On the logged in overview, I click any link (eg. list all patients)
- I get logged out and thrown back to the landing page

This happens only on Google Chrome. Here are the relevant entries from the access.log - can anyone make sense of these? I don't have any knowledge of HTTP status codes.

```
[03/Sep/2019:13:29:09 +0200] "POST /OpenClinica/j_spring_security_check HTTP/1.1" 302 328 "http://my-url.com/OpenClinica/pages/login/login;jsessionid=E6A0E2838AA51B1DA9F6AED47C42D5CD" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36"
[03/Sep/2019:13:29:09 +0200] "GET /OpenClinica/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 177 "http://my-url.com/OpenClinica/pages/login/login;jsessionid=E6A0E2838AA51B1DA9F6AED47C42D5CD" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36"
[03/Sep/2019:13:29:09 +0200] "GET /OpenClinica/MainMenu HTTP/1.1" 200 8269 "http://my-url.com/OpenClinica/favicon.ico" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36"
[03/Sep/2019:13:29:10 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 302 421 "http://my-url.com/OpenClinica/MainMenu" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36"
[03/Sep/2019:13:29:10 +0200] "GET /OpenClinica/pages/login/login;jsessionid=EA92FE865CF5345428D7538D18871D99 HTTP/1.1" 200 4770 "http://my-url.com/OpenClinica/MainMenu" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36"
```

Click on List all patients

```
[03/Sep/2019:13:29:12 +0200] "GET /OpenClinica/ListStudySubjects HTTP/1.1" 302 272 "http://my-url.com/OpenClinica/MainMenu" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36"
[03/Sep/2019:13:29:12 +0200] "GET /OpenClinica/pages/login/login HTTP/1.1" 200 4770 "http://my-url.com/OpenClinica/MainMenu" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36"
[03/Sep/2019:13:29:12 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 302 422 "http://my-url.com/OpenClinica/pages/login/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36"
[03/Sep/2019:13:29:12 +0200] "GET /OpenClinica/pages/login/login;jsessionid=9625D469100D1871538197FE241DECCB HTTP/1.1" 200 4770 "http://my-url.com/OpenClinica/pages/login/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36"
[03/Sep/2019:13:29:12 +0200] "GET /OpenClinica/RssReader HTTP/1.1" 200 757 "http://my-url.com/OpenClinica/pages/login/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36"
```

Now I do have some whacky redirect rules, which I think are the root cause of the problem. They were written as a fix to a different problem - when logging in to the system, instead of regularly looking at the favicon, the browser (any browser) would attempt to OPEN the favicon.ico as a picture, leading to, depending on the browser, a 404 page or the favicon being opened as a picture full screen. Here are the redirect rules:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  ServerName www.my-url.com

  ProxyPreserveHost On

  ProxyPass /OpenClinica/favicon.ico http://localhost:8080/OpenClinica/
  ProxyPassReverse /OpenClinica/favicon.ico http://localhost:8080/OpenClinica/

  ProxyPass /OpenClinica/ http://localhost:8080/OpenClinica/
  ProxyPassReverse /OpenClinica/ http://localhost:8080/OpenClinica/

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/OpenClinica/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/OpenClinica/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not used the specific application. As I see it, if you login while on `/` and you receive a cookie that is for `/OpenClinica/` then: clicking on a relative link (that will keep you on `/`) would prevent the browser from re-sending the received cookie to the server.

I would replace the last 2 entries with something like:

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /OpenClinica/
```

I did not exactly understand the issue with favicon but maybe you want to apply the same rule there.

Note: For [RedirectMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) to work  , [mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html) should be enabled.

Another thing: I see `ProxyPreserveHost` enabled. This means that `OpenClinica` should be aware of its external host name.

Answer (score 0):

So that server is listening to port `:80`, but those proxy rules are all on port `:8080` ... while I merely wonder why you need to configure proxy rules on `localhost`?

Just drop all of them and ignore the favicon issue meanwhile... the `jsessionid` being passed along with the URL rather hints for the server not handling the session properly, because such ID usually belongs into the request headers; putting them into the URL is the fallback option (because anyone who can see the logs can hijack these sessions, while in progress... no need for a password). With HTTPS it's not that bad, but on HTTP this is also visible in eventual proxy logs.

Honestly, I don't think this is a Chrome problem, but rather the vhost configuration and/or sessions problem.
It seems to stem from the vhost not having a `DocumentRoot` directive - and so it will inherit the global configuration, which seems to be one level above `/OpenClinica`.

Comment: When I remove all the rules, the favicon issue will return and I will receive a 404 page (or huge favicon.ico image in the browser window) upon login. Where should I start to look by your suggestion?

Comment: just rename to `favicon.bak` and setup that vhost properly; possibly the server does not have certain modules loaded. This question is generally pretty abstract, when only seeing a tiny bit of non-sense server configurations, which are probably useless, if only that virtual host had been setup properly.

Comment: It could as well be, that the server cannot create the session file or record. Sessions are in general always bound to paths, so when the requests are delivered in a strange way, it might affect these, too... and there is no `DocumentRoot` nor anything else configured for that vhost. Not all web-applications like to run from subdirectories.

Comment: For that 404, just see the server logs... I'd assume either failure to start the session server-side and/or the wrong entry-point for the application.